# Using RSS content to display posts in custom placeholders

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rss

I'm doing up my website and up until now, I've been using an RSS feed widget. Well, I want to do something a little more stylish (something that really fits with my website). Basically, what I want to do - is get RSS titles, images, short post content and post times from my websites RSS feed, and display it in nice fancy placeholders that I have on the homepage. Here is my homepage code (specifically the Recent Posts section):

```
    <div id="templatemo-blog">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="templatemo-line-header" style="margin-top: 0px;" >
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <hr class="team_hr team_hr_left hr_gray"/><span class="span_blog txt_darkgrey">BLOG POSTS</span>
                        <hr class="team_hr team_hr_right hr_gray" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br class="clearfix"/>
            </div>
            <div class="blog_box">
                <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-6 blog_post">
                    <ul class="list-inline">
                        <li class="col-md-4">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/blog-image-1.jpg" alt="gallery 1" />
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li  class="col-md-8">
                            <div class="pull-left">
                                <span class="blog_header">This Post</span><br/>
                                <span>Posted by : <a class="link_orange" href="#"><span class="txt_orange">Tracy</span></a></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="pull-right">
                                <a class="btn btn-orange" href="#" role="button">21 February 2084</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                            <p class="blog_text">
                                Aliquam quis rutrum risus, ut condimentum ipsum. Nullam aliquet libero augue, eget auctor felis vulputate id. Proin a enim eu libero ornare malesuada. Sed iaculis fringilla lacinia. Sed laoreet lectus vitae [...]
                            </p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div> <!-- /.blog_post 1 -->

                <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-6 blog_post">
                    <ul class="list-inline">
                        <li class="col-md-4"><a href="#">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="images/blog-image-2.jpg" alt="gallery 2" /></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-md-8">
                            <div class="pull-left">
                                <span class="blog_header">WEBSITE TEMPLATE</span><br/>
                                <span>Posted by : <a class="link_orange" href="#"><span class="txt_orange">Mary</span></a></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="pull-right">
                                <a class="btn btn-orange" href="#" role="button">18 February 2084</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                            <p class="blog_text">
                                    Morbi imperdiet ipsum sit amet dui pharetra, vulputate porta neque tristique. Quisque id turpis tristique, venenatis erat sit amet, venenatis turpis. Ut tellus ipsum, posuere bibendum [...]
                            </p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>   
                </div><!-- /.blog_post 2 -->

                <div class="templatemo_clear"></div>

                <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-6 blog_post">
                    <ul class="list-inline">
                        <li class="col-md-4"><a href="#">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="images/blog-image-2.jpg" alt="gallery 3" /></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-md-8">
                            <div class="pull-left">
                                <span class="blog_header">WEB DEVELOPMENT</span><br/>
                                <span>Posted by : <a class="link_orange" href="#"><span class="txt_orange">Julia</span></a></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="pull-right">
                                <a class="btn btn-orange" href="#" role="button">14 February 2084</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                            <p class="blog_text">
                                    Fusce molestie tellus risus, id commodo turpis convallis id. Morbi mattis sapien sapien, vitae lacinia ante interdum sit amet. Praesent eget varius diam, ac tempor est. Mauris at scelerisque magna [...]
                            </p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>   
                </div><!-- /.blog_post 3 -->

                <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-6 blog_post">
                    <ul class="list-inline">
                        <li class="col-md-4">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/blog-image-1.jpg"  alt="gallery 4" />
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-md-8">
                            <div class="pull-left">
                                <span class="blog_header">NEW FLUID LAYOUT</span><br/>
                                <span>Posted by : <a class="link_orange" href="#"><span class="txt_orange">Linda</span></a></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="pull-right">
                                <a class="btn btn-orange" href="#" role="button">11 February 2084</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                            <p class="blog_text">
                                In venenatis sodales purus a cursus. Ut consectetur, libero ac elementum tristique, enim ante aliquet mauris, scelerisque congue magna neque ac purus. Aliquam facilisis volutpat odio [...]
                            </p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div> <!-- /.blog_post 4 -->

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is visual reference of the above code: [image]

Basically, what I want to do - is replace the information that is pre-set there (from the template i'm referencing), but I have no idea how to do that. If required, I'd be happy to upload the entire project (HTML, CSS, JS, IMG). I appreciate in advance for any help :)

Comment: _Basically, what I want to do - is replace the information that is pre-set there (from the template i'm referencing), but I have no idea how to do that._
Could you please describe more?

Comment: Well, as you can see - the sample blog posts are apart of the template. What I want to do is for example, replace "This Post" with the title of a recent RSS post, and the description with a small snippet of that posts content.

Comment: I assume that you already have code for getting data from RSS feed using AJAX. Having done that, you just need to generate the `div.blog_post` dynamically and display it as shown in the template code that you have! Am I right?

Comment: No, I haven't got anything. I've never played around with RSS

Comment: Is you website online or local? Are you using PHP or any other server-side scripting language?

Comment: It's online, you can view it directly at www.rp-sa.net